# MGF of a probability function

Tags: probability, moment-generating-functions

The MGF of p(Y=y) = Σ(from 0 to y) c(n,x) * p^x * (1-p)^(n-x) + c(n-y,y-x) * p(y-x) * (1-p)^(n-x).

Comment: Isn't this just the MGF of the sum of two independent binomials $B(n,p)$? Then the MGF is the product of binomial MGFs.

Comment: @AlexR. Yeah, but n and p do not take on a single value. Rather, it is a summation of the product of two binomials. MGF itself contains a summation, so it would be a double summation when solving for MGF. Do I treat it as if without the summation?

Comment: Assuming your sum is indexed over $x$, it’s clearly the convolution of two binomial PDFs which is equivalent to adding two independent copies of them. Again, the MGF of a sum of independent random variables is equal to the product of MGFs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need an MGF.  Pull all of the powers to $n$ and as much of those to $y$ out of the sum as possible.

$$\begin{align}P(Y=y) &= \sum_{x= 0}^y \binom n x ~ p^x ~ (1-p)^{n-x} ~ \binom {n-x}{y-x} ~ p^{{y-x}} ~ (1-p)^{n-y}\\[1ex]&=p^y~(1-p)^{2n-y}~\sum_{x=0}^y\frac{n!}{x!~(y-x)!~(n-y)!}~(1-p)^{-x}\\[1ex]&=\binom{n}{y}p^y~(1-p)^{2(n-y)}~\sum_{x=0}^y\binom{y}{x}~(1-p)^{y-x}\end{align}$$

Now recall the binomial expansion: $$\sum_{x=0}^y\binom yx~a^{x}~b^{y-x}=(a+b)^y$$